# why there is Web error date string mistake?

Tags: date, error-handling, web-applications, compiler-errors

I'm typing a date in a web billing application and it says that "  Conversion from string "30/11/2022 00:00:00" to type 'Date' is not valid. " what should I do

image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8McR3.png)

I'm trying to get month wise sale

Comment: Hello Mitul Is this your web application ? If yes so can you please provide your code?

Comment: Hello Harsh, That's not my code. this is a website made for Gujarat Govt by NIC. for owners who runs FPS shops. While I was searching datewise sale this error was showed up. and its still there till date.

Comment: Hey Mitul, Ensure that the date format you entered matches the expected format in the web billing application. In some cases, the expected format may be different, such as "11/30/2022" instead of "30/11/2022."

Comment: Thank so much HARSH BHAI for answering, I've tried this too. evrything you could imagine. but it isn't working. is there anything or any method with which i can see the date format these guys have inserted?

Comment: You can check their documentation and also you can ask help from their contact support.

Comment: Thank you Harsh  Bhai, I've contacted NIC for further assistance. glad you noticed my query. thank you again.